# conditionally setting style attribute depending on an image's size, fetched through url

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, material-ui

My goal is to be able to pass in an image url and decide, depending on its dimensions, whether or not I want to use it. In order to accomplish this, I am using a function I found on stack overflow that is supposed to be able to return dimensions of an image using just the url.

This was the exact code they answered:

```
function getMeta(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height)
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

For my purposes, I need to be able to evaluate the width and height, so I modified as such, and let me know if I broke some major rule of js:

```
function getMeta(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        return [this.width, this.height]
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

With this function, I am able to call it with another function that I cooked up:

```
function backgroundCss(url){
    const dims = getMeta(url);
    return (dims[0] >= 1000 && dims[1] >= 300) ? `url(${url})` : "none"
}
```

and call it in my style attribute:

```
<Grid item xs={15} md={6} style={{
      backgroundImage: backgroundCss(url)
}}>
```

To my untrained eye, my approach seems pretty reasonable and error-free, but I keep getting this error saying Image() is not defined. (for what it's worth, I tried simply copy pasting the unchanged version of the function and calling it with a button, and it worked fine, alerting me onload with the dimensions)

[image]

I got the same error when trying a slightly different approach:

```
const [imageText, setImageText] = React.useState(null);
function getMeta(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    if(imageText == null){
        img.onload = () => setImageText((img.width >= 1000 && img.height >= 300) ? `url(${url})` : "none");
        getMeta(url);
        return false;
    }
    return imageText;
}
...
<Grid item xs={15} md={6} style={{
      backgroundImage: getMeta(url)
}}>
```

**Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Where did I go wrong here?**

Edit: is this the right direction?

```
function getMeta(url){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            resolve([this.width, this.height]);
        };
        img.src = url;
    })
}

function backgroundCss(url) {
    getMeta(url).then((dims) => {
        return (dims[0] >= 1000 && dims[1] >= 300) ? `url(${url})` : "none"
    })
}
```

Comment: It is complaining that `Image` is undefined. Try swapping it with `document.createElement('img')`

Comment: probably defined? the first function works, and that's using `Image`, so I think it's a bigger problem. It's not something I ever see people saying to import @Rikin

Comment: I just looked it up and apparently it is valid JS constructor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image May be React thinks otherwise, not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem #1, asynchronous code

Your `return` statement inside the `onload` handler isn't doing what you think:

```js
function getMeta(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        return [this.width, this.height]
        // ^^^ this returns for the `onload` handler, not `getMeta`
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

In order to fix this, you'd need to either use a "callback" or a `Promise` so you can asynchronously provide the return value once it's available.

#### Callback

```js
function getMeta(url, callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        // trigger the provided callback with the return value
        callback([this.width, this.height]);
    };
    img.src = url;
}

// used like so
getMeta('...', (dims) => {
    console.log(dims);
});
```

#### Promise

```js
function getMeta(url, callback){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            // resolve the promise with the return value
            resolve([this.width, this.height]);
        };
        img.src = url;
    })
}

// used like so
getMeta('...').then((dims) => {
    console.log(dims);
});
```

## Problem #2, react asynchronous rendering

Since react component render functions are synchronous, I believe you'll need to add some state for this. You could use  another `useState` hook like the one you already have. Something like:

```js
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState(null);

//...

// update the state once it's available
getMeta('...').then((dims) => {
    setImageUrl('...');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - I'm a little more familiar with promises so I opted to go that route and have updated the bottom of my answer to show how I interpreted your answer, which at the moment I've tried printing as raw html and my `backgroundCss` function isn't returning anything

Comment: @ark0n I added some info about using it with react